# mouseleave() event not working on just one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Jquery (and JavaScript for that matter) and I've been trying to made a sidebar where hovering over icons would show their respective div elements (the "sidebar" if you will).

I want it to behave so that whenever you mouse out of the #nav and the sidebars (#links, #updates), they would disappear from view (I am using the animate method and setting the opacity to 0). This works for #updates, but not the #links element...

I wonder if it's because how I've written the code, the mouseleave event for #links is not working? Everything works except for that.

I have a CodePen for what I'm working on right here: https://codepen.io/fleche/pen/qVNzMG

```js
$(".quicklinks").hover(function() {
         $("#links").animate({'opacity': 1}, 300);
}),
  
$("#links").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': 0}, 300);
}),

$(".announcements").hover(function() {
         $("#updates").animate({'opacity': 1}, 300);
}),
  
$("#updates").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': 0}, 300);
}),

$(".announcements").hover(function() {
         $("#links").animate({'opacity': 0}, 300);
}),

$(".quicklinks").hover(function() {
         $("#updates").animate({'opacity': 0}, 300);
}),

$("#nav").hover(function() {
  $("#links").stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, 300),
  $("#updates").stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, 300)
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,400i,700,700i|Work+Sans:400,600');

body { background-color: #ccc; font-family: Arial; }

#nav { background-color: #fff; width: 50px; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999; }

.homebutton, .quicklinks, .announcements { width: 50px; position: fixed; z-index: 9999; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; padding: 17px 0px; font-size:11px; text-align:center; background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px dotted #b5b8c0; color: #3f4f79; }

.homebutton { top: 0; left: 0; }
.quicklinks { top: 50px; left: 0; }
.announcements { top: 100px; left: 0; border-bottom: 0px solid; }

.quicklinks:hover, .announcements:hover { color: #b5b8c0; }

#links, #updates { position: fixed; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 50px; index: 99; background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.85); width: 180px; color: #fff; padding: 30px; opacity: 0; }

#links h1, #updates h1 { font-family: 'Work Sans'; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px; padding: 5px; background-color: #5c6274; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.navlinks a { display: block; padding: 4px 0px; font-family: 'Work Sans'; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px; text-decoration: none; color: #86898c; transition: all ease 0.4s; }

.navlinks a b { margin-right: 8px; font-weight: 600; color: #5c6274; }

#updates p { white-space: pre-line; font-size: 10px; color: #9a9a9a; font-family: 'Work Sans'; margin-bottom: 20px; line-height: 130%; text-align: left; }

#updates p b { color: #5c6274; margin-right: 4px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
</div>
 
  <div class="homebutton"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  
  <div class="quicklinks"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

<div class="announcements"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  
<div id="links">
  <h1>QUICK LINKS</h1><br>
  <div class="navlinks">
    <a href="#"><b>01</b> LINK</a>
    <a href="#"><b>02</b> LINK</a>
    <a href="#"><b>03</b> LINK</a>
    <a href="#"><b>04</b> LINK</a>
    <a href="#"><b>05</b> LINK</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="updates"><h1>updates</h1>
  <p><b>NOV/06</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam porta, velit et hendrerit tincidunt, metus erat tempus ante, in ullamcorper quam nisi in nisi. Suspendisse sed pulvinar ipsum.</p>
    
  <p><b>OCT/31</b> Suspendisse lectus ipsum, egestas pharetra egestas vitae, ultricies et mi. Ut condimentum nibh et vulputate aliquam. Nullam cursus libero rhoncus lorem auctor, at molestie ex cursus. Morbi finibus ipsum ac erat rhoncus, et convallis metus bibendum.</p> 
    
  <p><b>SEP/18</b> Aenean a porttitor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce porta, sapien vitae placerat tincidunt, purus mi feugiat diam, in gravida sem nisi suscipit nulla. Etiam odio lacus, maximus non lobortis ac, condimentum id magna.</p>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm sure there must be a better way to organize/rewrite my code, but I'm still a total newbie at this so if anyone could help me out, that would be awesome!

Comment: You've written `$("#links").mouseout(function(){` instead of `$("#links").mouseleave(function(){`

Comment: Actually I had originally written it with .mouseleave first, and tried .mouseout but both didn't work! ): Sorry about that, should've fixed it first before I posted it!

Comment: This might be hard to catch, but the elements are still *visible* in the eye of the browser, so your `#updates` is blocking all mouse events since it is higher in the z-axis. Try using `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` instead of `.animate`. the `fade` functions will set the element to `display:none;` after the animation, so no elements will messed up your mouse events.

Comment: That's a good catch! I tried using fadeIn() and fadeOut() but the results are that when I refresh the page, both the #links and #updates elements are visible. How do I start with them already hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be hard to catch, but the elements are still visible in the eye of the browser, so your `#updates` is blocking all mouse events since it is higher in the z-axis. Try using `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut` instead of `.animate`. the `fade` functions will set the element to `display:none;` after the animation, so no elements will mess up your mouse events.

Also, your divs should be set to `display:none;` instead of `opacity:0;` in the css.

**Please note that I made various changes to your JS to make it works better.**

```js
$("#links").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
});
  
$("#updates").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
});

$(".announcements").mouseenter(function() {
         $("#links").fadeOut(300);
         $("#updates").fadeIn(300);
});

$(".quicklinks").mouseenter(function() {
         $("#updates").fadeOut(300);
         $("#links").fadeIn(300);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,400i,700,700i|Work+Sans:400,600');

body { background-color: #ccc; font-family: Arial; }

#nav { background-color: #fff; width: 50px; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999; }

.homebutton, .quicklinks, .announcements { width: 50px; position: fixed; z-index: 9999; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; padding: 17px 0px; font-size:11px; text-align:center; background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px dotted #b5b8c0; color: #3f4f79; }

.homebutton { top: 0; left: 0; }
.quicklinks { top: 50px; left: 0; }
.announcements { top: 100px; left: 0; border-bottom: 0px solid; }

.quicklinks:hover, .announcements:hover { color: #b5b8c0; }

#links, #updates { position: fixed; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 50px; index: 99; background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.85); width: 180px; color: #fff; padding: 30px; display:none; }

#links h1, #updates h1 { font-family: 'Work Sans'; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px; padding: 5px; background-color: #5c6274; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 10px; }

.navlinks a { display: block; padding: 4px 0px; font-family: 'Work Sans'; font-size: 9px; font-weight: 400; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px; text-decoration: none; color: #86898c; transition: all ease 0.4s; }

.navlinks a b { margin-right: 8px; font-weight: 600; color: #5c6274; }

#updates p { white-space: pre-line; font-size: 10px; color: #9a9a9a; font-family: 'Work Sans'; margin-bottom: 20px; line-height: 130%; text-align: left; }

#updates p b { color: #5c6274; margin-right: 4px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
</div>
 
  <div class="homebutton"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  
  <div class="quicklinks"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

<div class="announcements"><i class="fa fa-bullhorn" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  
<div id="links">
  <h1>QUICK LINKS</h1><br>
  <div class="navlinks">
    <a href="#"><b>01</b> LINK</a>
    <a href="#"><b>02</b> LINK</a>
    <a href="#"><b>03</b> LINK</a>
    <a href="#"><b>04</b> LINK</a>
    <a href="#"><b>05</b> LINK</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="updates"><h1>updates</h1>
  <p><b>NOV/06</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam porta, velit et hendrerit tincidunt, metus erat tempus ante, in ullamcorper quam nisi in nisi. Suspendisse sed pulvinar ipsum.</p>
    
  <p><b>OCT/31</b> Suspendisse lectus ipsum, egestas pharetra egestas vitae, ultricies et mi. Ut condimentum nibh et vulputate aliquam. Nullam cursus libero rhoncus lorem auctor, at molestie ex cursus. Morbi finibus ipsum ac erat rhoncus, et convallis metus bibendum.</p> 
    
  <p><b>SEP/18</b> Aenean a porttitor quam. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce porta, sapien vitae placerat tincidunt, purus mi feugiat diam, in gravida sem nisi suscipit nulla. Etiam odio lacus, maximus non lobortis ac, condimentum id magna.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! D'oh! I should've realised I shouldn't be using opacity. Thanks again!

Comment: There should probably also be some `mouseleave` events for the items on the side, because as it is, moving up from the Links button or down from the Updates button doesn't close anything.

Comment: @Herohtar Yes, everything depends on what OP needs though. Since she's new to JS and jQuery, I'll let her figure how, it will be good practice! In a perfect world, that kind of menu would be 100% CSS tbh.